# Execute method after Spring context initialized but before requests are accepted

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a spring boot app (2.3), is it possible to have a method be executed after context is initialized, but before the app starts to take requests? I don't know if becoming ready to accept requests is part of the spring context initialization or if that is a separate step.

Note that ideally if this method throws an exception, the service fails to start, but that is not a requirement.

I tried `ContextRefreshedEvent`. However, the app is accepting requests at that point. (While my `ContextRefreshedEvent` event listener method is executing, requests can come in and execute at the same time.)

(I can't use `@PostContruct`, because my method depends on many different beans being initialized.)

The specific use case is that I have a spring cloud config server. I want it to pre-load authentication data into cache prior to accepting requests. The loading of this data depends on bootstrap/app config files being loaded, `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` listener being called, beans being constructed, etc.

Comment: How do you anticipate your method accessing all of the dependencies that need to have been initialised? If you use dependency injection, any injected beans will have already been initialised. By this point the environment will have been prepared too. `@PostConstruct` (or implementing `InitializingBean`) is a good fit here so I’m hoping to understand why you don’t want to use it.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson PostConstruct might work. In the midst of my investigation, I ran across a stackoverflow answer that stated PostConstruct might be executed after a particular bean was initialized, but not after ALL beans were initialized. But I just re-read the documentation for PostConstruct and see that is not the case. I'll give it a try. Thanks! (I'll post back here based on the results.)

Comment: `@PostConstruct` is called after the bean itself has been constructed and its dependencies injected. All of its dependencies will also have been initialized.

Comment: I finally got back to this. @PostConstruct was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andy Wilkinson pointed out (thank you!), to do this, implement a bean's method with the desired behavior and add the @PostConstruct annotation. The method will be called after **all** beans are initialized (and environment prepared) but before the service starts taking requests.